# OpenRowSet - How to configure OLE DB Provider to be used for for distributed queries

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, configuration, openrowset

I have an Excel file with data and would like to update a table in database based on the data the Excel file contains.

To do that I want to use `OpenRowSet` command. But I get the error below when even I want to have a `SELECT` from the Excel data.

```
SELECT  exl.*
INTO #myExcelData
FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0'
,'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Dev\ExcelDataImport.xlsx; Extended Properties=''EXCEL 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'
,'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') AS exl
GO

OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.
```

As error message says, I think I should configure the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` to be able to use it for distributed queries like `OpenRowSet`. To do that I ran the commond below:

```
exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
```

Output message from the command above:

```
Configuration option 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
```

But still I get the same error when try to run the `OpenRowSet` query.Could you please give me some hints how to resolve this issue and get the OpenRowSet working?

My environments:

SQL Server 2008 R2, Excel Professional Plus 10 (32 bits)

Also the providers I have in Linked sever as as following:[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any chance that in fixing this for posting, you've broken the query? You have an unescaped single quote in your extended properties section.

Answer (score 3):

after installation Restart agent and server services

Enable OLEDB Driver in SQL Server

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

**I would recommend using SSIS**. As it has the flexibility to allow you to save the package and reuse it for subsequent runs and it can even be scheduled using sql agent job.

You are also compromising security by allowing ad-hoc distributed queries to run (changing it to 1).

I have tried the exact same query that you posted and it works for me.

```
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries',1
go
reconfigure with override
go
SELECT  exl.*
INTO #myExcelData
FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0'
,'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Documents and Settings\kin\Desktop\test_kin.xlsx; Extended Properties=''EXCEL 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'
,'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') AS exl
GO

select * from #myExcelData
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think the reason it's not working for me, is because I don't have 'Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0' among the providers as you specified in your answer. Could you please advise me how to add it? I've edited my question to include the provider lists I've got currently.

Comment: @NazilaBeikpour you have to download and install from [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: I installed it from the link above, reopen the SQL management studio but still this provider is not listed there. Is there anything else should be done to add it to the provider list?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to Add to 'Kin's answer and add that if you are running a 32 Bit office products and there for a 32 bit version of AccessDatabaseEngine which is what is used for communications to office products (Excel) Then you may have this issue, however if you change to 64 bit this should disappear. (and Ace will appear on your linked servers.)